# Problems with Broadcom bcm4311 wireless card on HP Pavillion dv6000

Tags: wireless, hp, broadcom

I hope someone can help out with this (I've tried all possible solutions proposed for similar problems, but non has solved the problem so far).

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 (for the first time in my life); everything looks ok, except for the wireless connection that won't work. The laptop I'm using is a dv6000 from HP; the wireless card is a broadcom bcm4311 - which apparently is prone to causing problems...

Answer (score 0):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and you wireless should be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer explains how to install the drivers manually, without an internet connection on the target computer.*

Using a second computer with an internet connection, download the files listed below to a removable USB drive.

Source: ubuntu launchpad.net

- b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb (23 KB)
- firmware-b43-installer_019-2_all.deb (4 KB)

http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/webfs

- webfs_1.21+ds1-10_amd64.deb (65 KB)

http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2

- broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2 (13.5 MB)

### Quick summary:

- Copy files from USB drive to home folder
- Install b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb = successful
- Install firmware-b43-installer_019-2_all.deb = fails because it needs to download broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
- Remedy by installing webfs (a light http server) and configuring the resources to match www.lwfinger.com
- Update the hosts file to resolve www.lwfinger.com to localhost
- Install firmware-b43-installer_019-2_all.deb = successful
- Restart computer
- Wireless connection now working

### Detailed instructions:

Install webfs (a light http server)

```
sudo dpkg -i webfs_1.21+ds1-10_amd64.deb
```

Configure the web server to match www.lwfinger.com

```
sudo nano /etc/webfsd.conf
```

Note down the web_root value and change the web_port value to 80

```
web_root="/var/www"
web_port="80"
```

Navigate to the web_root folder, create the b43-firmware sub folder, and move broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2 into it

```
cd /var/www
sudo mkdir b43-firmware
sudo mv ~/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2 ./b43-firmware
```

Restart the web server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/webfs restart
```

Finally edit the hosts file to complete the configuration.

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add the following entry

```
127.0.0.1       www.lwfinger.com
```

Install b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb

```
sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_019-2_amd64.deb
```

Install firmware-b43-installer_019-2_all.deb

```
sudo dpkg -i firmware-b43-installer_019-2_all.deb
```

Restart the computer, you should now have your wireless connection operating as normal.

For record sake this is the output you would get without the above procedure in place.

```
Selecting previously unselected package firmware-b43-installer.
(Reading database ... 171103 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack firmware-b43-installer_019-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-b43-installer (1:019-2) ...
Setting up firmware-b43-installer (1:019-2) ...
No chroot environment found. Starting normal installation
--2015-08-31 15:25:30--  http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
Resolving www.lwfinger.com (www.lwfinger.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.lwfinger.com’
Some problem occurred during the firmware download. Please check your internet connection.
```

This is the output you should get with the above procedure executed correctly.

```
(Reading database ... 171109 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack firmware-b43-installer_019-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-b43-installer (1:019-2) over (1:019-2) ...
Setting up firmware-b43-installer (1:019-2) ...
No chroot environment found. Starting normal installation
--2015-08-31 15:32:16--  http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
Resolving www.lwfinger.com (www.lwfinger.com)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to www.lwfinger.com (www.lwfinger.com)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 13514651 (13M) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2’

broadcom-wl-5.100.1 100%[=====================>]  12.89M  --.-KB/s   in 0.05s  

2015-08-31 15:32:16 (285 MB/s) - ‘broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2’ saved [13514651/13514651]

Deleting old extracted firmware...
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_ap.o
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_sta.o
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/README
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wlconfig_lx_shared
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wl.mk
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wl_default
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wl_hnd
broadcom-wl-5.100.138/config/wlconfig_nomimo
This file is recognised as:
  filename   :  wl_apsta.o
  version    :  666.2
  MD5        :  e1b05e268bcdbfef3560c28fc161f30e
Extracting b43/lp0initvals14.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals17.fw
Extracting b43/ucode17_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_lp.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1initvals27.fw
Extracting b43/lp2bsinitvals19.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn3bsinitvals21.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_sslpn.fw
  ucode time:     01:15:07
Extracting b43/ucode25_lcn.fw
Extracting b43/ucode21_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals14.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals9.fw
Extracting b43/ucode20_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals9.fw
Extracting b43/lp1initvals20.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals13.fw
Extracting b43/lp2initvals19.fw
Extracting b43/n2bsinitvals19.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn4bsinitvals22.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_sslpn_nobt.fw
  ucode date:     2011-02-23
Extracting b43/n1bsinitvals20.fw
Extracting b43/n1initvals20.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode22_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals13.fw
Extracting b43/ht0initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/ucode33_lcn40.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1bsinitvals20.fw
Extracting b43/lcn400bsinitvals33.fw
Extracting b43/ucode14.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0initvals5.fw
Extracting b43/lp1bsinitvals22.fw
Extracting b43/n16initvals30.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals16.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/lcn400initvals33.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals22.fw
Extracting b43/n18initvals32.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals5.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals11.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0initvals26.fw
Extracting b43/n0absinitvals11.fw
Extracting b43/ucode21_sslpn_nobt.fw
  ucode time:     01:15:07
Extracting b43/ucode26_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/n2initvals19.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn3initvals21.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1bsinitvals13.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn4initvals22.fw
Extracting b43/pcm5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode22_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode9.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/lp1initvals22.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1bsinitvals27.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/ucode32_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0bsinitvals9.fw
Extracting b43/n18bsinitvals32.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode24_lcn.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals17.fw
Extracting b43/n0bsinitvals16.fw
Extracting b43/lp0initvals15.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0initvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ucode20_sslpn_nobt.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1initvals24.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn0initvals16.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals13.fw
Extracting b43/lp1bsinitvals20.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn2initvals19.fw
Extracting b43/a0g1initvals9.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/ucode5.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals13.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals16.fw
Extracting b43/ucode19_sslpn_nobt.fw
Extracting b43/b0g0bsinitvals9.fw
Extracting b43/ucode11.fw
Extracting b43/lp0initvals16.fw
Extracting b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/ht0initvals29.fw
Extracting b43/lcn2bsinitvals25.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0initvals9.fw
Extracting b43/ucode29_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0bsinitvals24.fw
Extracting b43/ucode19_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/ucode30_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/n16bsinitvals30.fw
Extracting b43/ucode25_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode24_mimo.fw
Extracting b43/ucode27_sslpn.fw
Extracting b43/lp0initvals13.fw
Extracting b43/a0g0bsinitvals5.fw
Extracting b43/ht0bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/ucode13.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn2bsinitvals19.fw
Extracting b43/ucode15.fw
Extracting b43/lp0bsinitvals15.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals11.fw
Extracting b43/lcn0initvals25.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn0bsinitvals16.fw
Extracting b43/sslpn1initvals20.fw
Extracting b43/lcn1bsinitvals26.fw
Extracting b43/n0initvals22.fw
Extracting b43/ht0bsinitvals29.fw
```